# How to input <CR> into ex command from script or commandline?

Tags: command-line, ex-mode

I recorded a macro, that has an enter in it `ggd/{<CR>Gdd` but of course  is `^M`. What I want to do is run this on a bunch of files from the commandline which I guess would be something like

```
ex +"normal ggd/{<CR>Gdd" +wq
```

but how do I put an actual enter where it should go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ex +"exe \"normal! ggd/{\<CR>\"" +"normal! Gdd" +"wq"
```

Basically you need to use `:execute` where you can pass `\<CR>` inside a double-quoted string

**UPD** as suggested in comments:

```
ex +'exe "normal! ggd/{\<CR>"' +'$d' +wq
```